# Select only those records with matches all given conditions in reference table with Hibernate and Oracle

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I have tables Student(std_id, std_name), Subject(sub_id, sub_name) and one mapping table Sudent_Subject(std_id, sub_id)

Want to fetch list of all the students with having only given subject say Maths and Science and not other than this subject or not less than given subjects.

In this case, I have configured above tables with hibernate. Here are required POJO

```
    Class Student {
        private String std_id;
        private String std_name;
        List<Subject> lstSubject;
    }

    Class Subject {
        private String sub_id;
        private String sub_name;
        List<Student> lstStudent;
    }
```

Is it possible to write HQL to get required result? Also, how we can achieve this result using plain SQL?

Answer (score 1):

> *Also, how we can achieve this result using plain SQL?*

You could use `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT s.std_id, s.name
FROM Student s
JOIN Student_Subject ss
  ON s.std_id = ss.std_id
JOIN Subject sb
  ON sb.sub_id = ss.sub_id
GROUP BY s.std_id, s.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN sb.sub_name IN ('Math', 'Science') THEN 1 END) = 2;
```

Comment: With same logic, I am trying to convert above query in HQL but it fails with `org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: case near line 1` exception. Any Idea how we can use `CASE` keyword after `WHERE`.